# Correct use of Boost::asio inside of a separate thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-asio

I am writing a DLL plugin for the [Orbiter space simulator](http://orbit.medphys.ucl.ac.uk/), which allows for UDP communication with an external system. I've chosen boost::asio for the task, as it allows me to abstract from the low-level stuff.

The "boundary conditions" are as follows:

1. I can create any threads or call any API functions from my DLL
2. I can modify the data inside of the simulation only inside the callback passed to my DLL (each frame), due to lack of other thread safety.

Hence, I chose the following architecture for the NetworkClient class I'm using for communications:

- Upon construction, it initializes the UDP socket (boost::socket+boost::io_service) and starts a thread, which calls io_service.run()
- Incoming messages are put asyncronously into a queue (thread-safe via CriticalSection)
- The callback processing function can pull the messages from queue and process it

However, I have run into some strange exception upon running the implementation:
    boost::exception_detail::clone_impl > at memory location 0x01ABFA00.

The exception arises in io_service.run() call.

Can anyone point me, please, am I missing something? The code listings for my classes are below.

NetworkClient declaration:

```
class NetworkClient {
public:
    NetworkClient(udp::endpoint server_endpoint);
    ~NetworkClient();

    void Send(shared_ptr<NetworkMessage> message);
    inline bool HasMessages() {return incomingMessages.HasMessages();};
    inline shared_ptr<NetworkMessage> GetQueuedMessage() {return incomingMessages.GetQueuedMessage();};

private:
    // Network send/receive stuff
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    udp::socket socket;
    udp::endpoint server_endpoint;
    udp::endpoint remote_endpoint;
    boost::array<char, NetworkBufferSize> recv_buffer;

    // Queue for incoming messages
    NetworkMessageQueue incomingMessages;

    void start_receive();
    void handle_receive(const boost::system::error_code& error, std::size_t bytes_transferred);
    void handle_send(boost::shared_ptr<std::string> /*message*/, const boost::system::error_code& /*error*/, std::size_t /*bytes_transferred*/) {}
    void run_service();

    NetworkClient(NetworkClient&); // block default copy constructor
};
```

Methods implementation:

```
NetworkClient::NetworkClient(udp::endpoint server_endpoint) : socket(io_service, udp::endpoint(udp::v4(), 28465)) {
    this->server_endpoint = server_endpoint;
    boost::thread* th = new boost::thread(boost::bind(&NetworkClient::run_service,this));
    start_receive();
}

void NetworkClient::start_receive()
{
    socket.async_receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(recv_buffer), remote_endpoint,
        boost::bind(&NetworkClient::handle_receive, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred)
    );
}
void NetworkClient::run_service()
{
    this->io_service.run();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your architecture that I can see. You should catch exceptions thrown from `io_service::run()`, that is likely the source of your problem.

```
void NetworkClient::run_service()
{
    while(1) {
        try {
            this->io_service.run();
        } catch( const std::exception& e ) {
            std::cerr << e.what << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

You'll also want to fix whatever is throwing the exception.

Comment: Thank you very much! Should have guessed myself, but worried too much about the correctness :) Error turned out to be due to me not closing the io_service correctly (io_service.stop()).